# Windows Form DateTimePicker always open

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

I have one DateTimePicker on WindowsForm that should stay open for all life of the form.
How I can do that WITHOUT use the command by line to open it everytime CloseUp. I need something like a properties to prevent the closing.

Comment: Create a 2nd form.  See my two form project : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net/34975678.  I can exit from second form by setting e.Cancel = true;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `Calendar` instead of `DateTimePicker`

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for the tip of use MonthCalendar instead of DateTimePicker, it works for me.
To be a little clearer to further readers:

1. replace DateTimePicker with MonthCalendar
2. set the property `monthCalendar.MaxSelectionCount` to 1
3. use `monthCalendar.SelectionRange.Start` instead of `dtp.Value` to get the selected date